# Happstack display a read file

Tags: haskell, file-io, happstack

This is a Haskell newb question probably to do with the `IO()` monad.

I've got a function in a `Happstack.Server` program that generates a response for a file upload.

```
postFile = do methodM POST
              decodeBody filePolicy
              (tmp, name, meta) <- lookFile "upload"
              ok $ concat ["A file! ", tmp, " || ", name, " || ", show meta]
```

That works fine. Now, I'd like it to display the content of the uploaded file as well as its local tempname, original name and content-type metadata. I was assuming that since this is all taking place in a `do` block, I could just

```
postFile = do methodM POST
              decodeBody filePolicy
              (tmp, name, meta) <- lookFile "upload"
              contents <- readFile tmp
              ok $ concat ["A file! ", tmp, " || ", name, " || ", show meta, "\n\n", contents]
```

but that hands me a string of errors that seems to tell me something is up with the `decodeBody` call.

```
...
/home/inaimathi/projects/happstack-tutorial/parameters.hs:23:15:
    No instance for (Happstack.Server.Internal.Monads.WebMonad
                       Response IO)
      arising from a use of `decodeBody'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Happstack.Server.Internal.Monads.WebMonad Response IO)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: decodeBody filePolicy
    In the expression:
      do { methodM POST;
           decodeBody filePolicy;
           (tmp, name, meta) <- lookFile "upload";
           contents <- readFile tmp;
           .... }
    In an equation for `postFile':
        postFile
          = do { methodM POST;
                 decodeBody filePolicy;
                 (tmp, name, meta) <- lookFile "upload";
                 .... }
...
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Can anyone educate me?

---

**EDIT3:**

That'll learn me to jump to conclusions.

The additional errors I was getting were all due to improperly installed libraries. Clearing out my `~/.ghc`, then installing `happstack` again fixed it.

Comment: Don't know Happstack, but you probably need to use `liftIO $ readFile tmp`.`

Comment: As others have said, you just need 'liftIO'. I will add a section to the Crash Course on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
No instance for (Happstack.Server.Internal.Monads.WebMonad
                       Response IO)
```

Translation: your `do`-block is not the IO monad but some other monad.  Fortunately, it turns out to be an instance of MonadIO:

```
class Monad m => MonadIO m where
    liftIO :: IO a -> m a
```

As you see, such an instance simply provides a way to 'lift' IO actions from the IO monad into itself, so in your case you just need:

```
contents <- liftIO $ readFile tmp
```

The implementation of `liftIO` obviously depends on `m`, but in a typical monad transformer stack it uses `lift` and `liftIO` to get to the IO monad inside; see e.g., the [implementations for the other monad transformers in the Transformers library](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html).

Comment: Added an edit to the question after trying this suggestion; it seems it's not quite as simple as adding `liftIO`.

Comment: `Happstack.Server.Internal.Monads.ServerPartT IO String` (`:t` in `ghci` reports `Happstack.Server.Internal.Monads.ServerPartT IO [Char]`)

Comment: I can't reproduce the `No instance for (Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO (Happstack.Server.Internal.Monads.ServerPartT IO))` issue.  Certainly the compiler should be able to deduce this instance from declarations in Happstack.Server.Internal.Monads and Control.Monad.IO.Class, so I'm confused.

Comment: A cosmetic suggestion -- the Internal modules aren't meant for use in applications, so you might consider giving `postFile` the type `ServerPart String` instead.

Comment: Added a type declaration of `postFile :: ServerPart String`, just to make it explicit. The version without `readFile` still works fine, but adding the additional assignment to `contents` gives me the same error.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you use any language pragmas when you tried to repro this?

Comment: Hmm. Looks like the latest error is a result of my machine architecture (your suggestion works fine on a 32-bit machine, but still fails as I note above on 64-bit).